# Validar datos con JavaScript un solo caracter

Tags: javascript

Necesito validar el campo "isofficial" de un formulario con JavaScript, quiero que este solo acepte "T" o "F" ya que la base de datos solo acepta uno de estos dos caracteres, así como ya tengo las instrucciones  para que ambos campos sean obligatorios y "percentage" sea un numero que pueda llevar decimales, quiero saber cual es la instruccion para que en campo "isofficial" solo acepte uno de los caracteres "T" o "F".

```
    function validate(){
    var
    isofficial,
    percentage;

    isofficial=document.getElementById("isofficial").value; 
    percentage=document.getElementById("percentage").value;

    if (isofficial===""||percentage==="") {
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
    return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(percentage)){
    alert("El campo percentage debe ser un numero puede tener decimales");
    return false;
    }

   }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar mas acerca de lo que necesitas?

Comment: @Juan Sinceramente, tu mejor solución sería usar un *checkbox* (incluso un *radio button*) y hacer tú mismo la conversión del *boolean* a `T` o `F`. De este modo te evitas muchos problemas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular o una condición `or(||)` para hacer tu validación.

```js
function isOfficial(value) {
  return value === "T" || value === "F";
}

// expresión regular
function isOfficialRegex(value) {
  const regex = /^[TF]$/;
  // ^ que empieze por T o F
  // [TF] rango de caracteres validos
  // $ acabe con T o F
  return regex.test(value)
}

document.getElementById('validate').addEventListener('click', e => {
   const isofficial=document.getElementById("isofficial").value; 
   console.log(isOfficial(isofficial));
   console.log("regex", isOfficialRegex(isofficial));
})
```

```html
<input id="isofficial" type="text"/>
<button id="validate">validar</button>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```
 function validate() {
   var isofficial, percentage;

   isofficial = document.getElementById("isofficial").value;
   percentage = document.getElementById("percentage").value;

   if (isofficial === "" || percentage === "") {
     alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
     return false;
   } else if (isNaN(percentage)) {
     alert("El campo percentage debe ser un numero puede tener decimales");
     return false;
    // cualquier caracter que sea distinto de T o F será incorrecto
   } else if (isofficial !== "T" && isofficial !== "F") {
     alert("El campo isofficial debe ser T o F");
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Espero que sea esto lo que buscas.

Comment: La respuesta es util pero necesito validar con JavaScript asi como tengo en los dos "if" anteriores, necesito solo la instruccion para agregarla en un "if"

Comment: a ver y esto que he respondido que es?  es Javascript. Sino necesitas todo puedes "coger" lo que te sirva. Bueno actualizo mi respuesta para poner el `if`

Comment: Al parecer si es lo que necesito muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya modifique mi código con tu respuesta, pero aun que agregue `T` o `F` me aparece la alerta de `El campo isofficial debe ser T o F`

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta, tenia que usar el operador `&&` (and) me equivoqué. Ahora debería funcionarte

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar el atributo `pattern` y luego al momento de hacer el submit evaluar la propiedad  `input.validity.valid`

```js
function validar(){  
  var esValido = document.getElementById("input-id").validity.valid;
  console.log('Es valido:', esValido);
  var esToF = document.getElementById("input-id").validity.patternMismatch;
  console.log('Es T o F:', esValido);
  // con logica booleana
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("input-id").value;
  esToF = inputValue == "T" || inputValue == "F";
  console.log('Es T o F:', esToF);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
     <input id='input-id' type='text' pattern='(^[T|F]$)' required />
     <button type='submit'onclick="return validar()" />Enviar</button> 
</form>
```

Con la propiedad `requiered` validas que los campos no se queden vacíos.

Podrás encontrar información detallada en el siguiente link: [HTML  pattern Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Esta herramienta en línea te pude ayudar a generar el patrón a evaluar: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: La respuesta es útil pero necesito validarlo con JavaScript